# How to pass a different argument conditionally

Tags: python

I want to be able to change an argument to a function when a condition is met.

Currently I am doing this which works, but I am repeating the first argument, is there a way to just change the second argument?

```
credential = './credentials.json'

if os.path.exists(credential):
  account = authenticate(client_config=secrets, credentials=credential)
else:
  account = authenticate(client_config=secrets, serialize=credential)
```

Comment: there is one syntax error and one minor mistake in Your code. first don't use `===` three equal signs and second You can do just `if not condition`

Comment: Yeah I fixed that and also changed it to check if file exists, but I want to avoid if else and maybe do some sort of ternary and just declare the function once

Comment: Is the "credentials" note the s a typo?

Comment: honestly none of these answers are shorter than Your code (probably are shorter in more complex cases)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your way is fine too, but you can do this

```py
credential = './credentials.json'
params = {'serialize': credential}
if os.path.exists(credentials):
  params['credentials'] = params.pop('serialize')

account = authenticate(client_config=secrets, **params)
```

Answer (score 3):

An elegant way is to use kwargs:

```
credential = './credentials.json'
key = "credentials" if os.path.exists(credentials) else "serialize"
auth_kwargs = {"client_config": secrets, key: credential}    

account = authenticate(**auth_kwargs)
```

Comment: bit confused. where does `key` get used?

Comment: @Matiiss Sorry I forgot to add it to the dict - fixed

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an (unpacked) dictionary to a function:

```
credential = './credentials.json'
arguments = {'client_config': secrets, 'serialize': credential}  # default

if os.path.exists(credentials):
    arguments.pop('serialize')
    arguments['credentials'] = credential

account = authenticate(**arguments)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) for this:

```
from functools import partial

credential = './credentials.json'

auth = partial(authenticate, client_config=secrets)

if os.path.exists(credential):
  account = auth(credentials=credential)
else:
  account = auth(serialize=credential)
```